# Extbase: PersistanceManager in Repository is NULL

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm building an extension for TYPO3 8 and maybe I don't understand the injection mechanisms well enough, but here is my situation:

I have written a service class to query an API.
Said service also gets some information from an local Repository:

```php
class ApiService {
    protected $myRepository

    public function __construct() {
        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
        $this->myRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyRepository::class, $objectManager);
        var_dump($this->myRepository->persistanceManager); # outputs NULL
    }

    public function callerFunction() {
        var_dump($this->myRepository->persistenceManager); # outputs NULL
        myRepository->someRepositoryFunction();
    }
}
```

This calls `myRepository->someRepositoryFunction()`:

```php
class MyRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {
     public function someRepositoryFunction() {
         var_dump($this->persistenceManager); # outputs a valid singleton PersistenceManager
         $data = $this->findAll(); # succeeds
     }
}
```

This code works when used in the **frontend controller**.

```php
class MyController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {
    /**
     * @var MyRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $myRepository = null;

    public function listAction() {
        myRepository->someRepositoryFunction();
    }
}
```

Somehow the first `var_dump` outputs `NULL`, while the second `var_dump` magically outputs a valid singleton.
`print_r`-statements in `Repository::__construct()` and `Repository::injectPersistenceManager()` seem not to be called. Therefore I can't explain where the PersistenceManager comes from all the sudden.

The simplfied stack trace:

```php
#0 MyExtension\Domain\Repository\MyRepository->someRepositoryFunction() called at [myExtension/Classes/Service/ApiService.php]
#1 MyExtension\Service\ApiService->callerFunction() called at [myExtension/Classes/Domain/Repository/AnotherRepository.php]
#2 MyExtension\Domain\Repository\AnotherRepository->someOtherRepositoryFunction() called at [myExtension/Classes/Controller/MyController.php]
#3 MyExtension\Controller\MyController->listAction()
```

Since the codes works that wouldn't be a big problem.
But if I call the same code from a **Task** class the PersistenceManager **stays** `NULL`.

```php
class MyTask extends AbstractTask
{

    protected $apiService = null;

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->apiService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ApiService::class);

        $data = $this->apiService->callerFunction();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Again the simplified Stacktrace:

```php
#0 MyExtension\Domain\Repository\MyRepository->someRepositoryFunction() called at [myExtension/Classes/Service/ApiService.php]
#1 MyExtension\Service\ApiService->callerFunction() called at [myExtension/Classes/Task/MyTask.php]
#2 MyExtension\Task\MyTask->execute() called at [typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Scheduler.php]
#3 TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler->executeTask() called at [typo3/sysext/scheduler/Classes/Controller/SchedulerModuleController.php]
```

This now throws a `Call to a member function createQueryForType() on null` because the PersistenceManager of MyRepository is `NULL`.

Note that MyRepository is instantiated in both cases by the ApiService!
So what difference does it make if I call it from a controller or a task?
`ApiService::__construct` is called in both cases. (Although the instances of `MyRepository` are still NULL at that point.)

Why does the PersistenceManager appear all the sudden?

Comment: When I instantiate the PersistenceManager manually in `MyRepository::__construct` the error happens a bit later. In that case the PM itself does not get a `QueryFactory` injected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$this->myRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MyRepository::class, $objectManager);
```

Try this:

```
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');
$this->myRepository = $objectManager->get(MyRepository::class);
```

The objectManager resolves all the dependency injections.